# Use a JSP variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to use a JSP variable in a .js file, but it doesn't populate anything in the variable. However, if I do the same in the jsp file inside   block, it works fine. In other words:

**Scenario#1**
**test.jsp** (keeping everything in a jsp file) - works fine!!!

```
final String[] CONTENT = Processor.getContent();
final String projects= CONTENT[0];

<script>
    function createPDD($container) {
        var $projects = JSON.parse('<%=projects%>'); // this works fine and show the list of projects.
    }
</script>
```

**Scenario#2** **test.jsp** (keeping the js code .js file) - doesn't work!!!

```
  <script src="test.js"> </script>
  final String[] CONTENT = Processor.getContent();
  final String projects= CONTENT[0];
```

**test.js**

```
function createPDD($container) {
    var $projects = JSON.parse('<%=projects%>'); // this doesn't work... $projects comes empty.
}
```

Please note, its not a js import path issue as other js functions in test.js work fine.

Comment: This is a fairly common issue. Depending on the situation, either a global js variable in the jsp or a small JS function inside the jsp that calls the 'full' js function is used.

Comment: Put `<script src="test.js"> </script>` after all jsp code and try onces.